# Maple: bug in Overview of the GF (Galois Field) Package?

Tags: maple

So I downloaded [sample (Download Help Document)](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GF) but I can not compile it - (last line fais with:

```
The use statement, if used carefully, can make arithmetic operations in the field much more natural.
y := G16:-`*`(a, G16:-`+`(a, x)); 1; z := G16:-`+`(a, G16:-`*`(-1, y)); 1; G16:-`+`(G16:-`^`(z, 3), G16:-`^`(y, 2));
                       /     2    \      
                       \alpha  + 1/ mod 2
                               1
Error, (in *) modp1: invalid arguments to function Multiply
                               1
Error, (in ^) modp1: invalid arguments to function Powmod
```

Shall my maple (15) work like this and this is a docs bug? And if yes how to fix it, or is it real maple (as application) bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the automatic conversion of the original 1D Maple Notation Example source to 2D Math input.

To see it in 1D Maple Notation, click the graphical icon in the Help viewer which lies farthest right on the menubar. (If you have balloon/hover-over tips enabled, then hovering the mouse pointer over that icon should reveal the pop-up message, "Display Examples with 2D Math". It's a toggle mechanism, and can be used to repeatedly switch some Examples to and from 2D/ID input.

As 1D Maple notation (after toggling in the Help window), it should appear as the plantext red code,

```
use G16 in
  y := a * ( a + x );
  z := a - y;
  z^3 + y^2
end use;
```

That should execute fine, if entered.

The bit that is being misconverted to 2D Math input form is

```
z := a - y;
```

which is becoming (in the `use` context),

```
z := G16:-`+`(a, G16:-`*`(-1, y));
```

which causes that first error message. It should probably be better converted, internally, as,

```
z := G16:-`-`(a, y);
```

I will submit a bug report on the Maple users forum [mapleprimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com).